# How to enable IntelliSense support for my Vue custom component library in VSCode

Tags: vue.js, intellisense

I'm currently working on a Vue project where I have created a custom component library for reusability across multiple applications. However, I'm facing an issue with IntelliSense support in Visual Studio Code (VSCode) for my custom components.

How to enable IntelliSense support for my Vue custom component library in VSCode? Specifically, I would like to know:

What steps should I follow to configure my project or VSCode settings to enable IntelliSense support for my custom component library?
Are there any additional dependencies or VSCode extensions I need to install to make IntelliSense work with custom components?
Are there any best practices or common pitfalls to avoid when configuring IntelliSense for Vue custom component libraries?

Any insights, tips, or code snippets would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Volar extension is installed:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Vue.volar