# How to comment VueJs Single-File-Components

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, documentation, intellisense, vue-sfc

I am writing a VueJs app, using typescript, and have mostly switched to Vue's new [script setup syntax](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html) for my single file compontents (SFC). I don't know **how to write comments that properly show up in VSCode's intellisense**.

I want to comment my SFC components, including an "overall" comment for the component itself.

Formerly, without the setup syntax, I did:

```
<script lang="ts">

/** Displays a track's artist info.....
 * @remarks This component ....
 */
export default defineComponent({
    name: 'ArtistInfo',
```

This worked not very well either, but the text actually showed up in the VSCode intellisense preview *inside* the component itself, when hovering over the `default` keyword:

[image: Intellisense inside the SFC]

It did not work from the outside, in code using the SFC component. In any case, using the setup syntax or not, it just gives a generic usage hint:

[image: Generic usage hint]

Now with the new [script setup syntax](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html) there is no obvious place to put the comment in the first place.

**Question: Where should I put component level comments for my SFC with the script setup syntax?** And: **What is needed to let VSCode's intellisense show it at usage time?**

NOTE

- I have installed the Volar extension as recommended here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76441150/79485 but it's not working either (only for properties etc,.. not the componenent itself)

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing down how I comment in code which perfectly work for in VS code.

1. Component Level Comment

[image]

2. Functional Comment

[image]

3. Props Comment

[image]

For any query, feel free to comment. :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Only the example 1 is relevant to me. I tried to mimic exactly your comment style, but it does not work, at least not in the template code. My comment only shows up when hovering over the import statement, which is less than expected. Can you show a screenshot from the component actually using "MyComponent"? What extensions do you have in VSCode?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541

Comment: @Marcel I'm using these extensions:
Vetur
Vue.js Extension Pack
ESlint
Prettier - Code formatter